# how to calculate a modified fibonacci via matrix exponentiation

Tags: recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers, matrix-equations

If I modify the fibonacci recurrence to be the following way:

f(0) = 1

f(1) = 1

f(N) = f(N - 1) + f(N - 2) + 1

Is it possible to represent this recurrence in a matrix equation similar to the one below? If so, how would I do write that?

[image]

Comment: Not quite, but looking at $g(n) = f(n) + 1$ may give you an idea.

Comment: Hum, so I would have to keep to matrices? I need that for a program, I know how to do matrix power but I'm not used to work with matrix, I thought about doing f and then adding one in the Fn but I'm not sure It would work

Comment: Have you found out what $g(n)$ is? You can use your Fibonacci matrix stuff, and only need a small modification afterwards.

Comment: not yet, before this problem all I had seen from matrix equations was linear systems: solving Ax = b, still thinking

Comment: What recurrence does $g(n)$ have?

Comment: f(n) = 2 fibonacci(n+1) - 1

Comment: g(n) + g(n + 1) = g(n + 2) - 1

Comment: @Alan do you have a link on how to get down to this formula? All I wanted to calculate was: how many recursive calls fib(N) would have and was struggling for a while, your formula seems awesome! thanks

Comment: Sure , check out , this post on OEIS: https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C3%2C5%2C9%2C15%2C25&sort=&language=english&go=Search

Answer (score 2):

While Daniel Fischer's approach in comments is the straighter approach, we can also express $\{f_n\}$  via matrix multiplication as

$$
\begin{pmatrix} f_{n+2}\\ f_{n+1} \\ 1\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} f_{n+1}\\ f_{n} \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\tag{1}
.
$$

So the only change needed is to use a 3-by-3 matrix to generate this modified Fibonacci sequence.

---

To draw a direct linkage to Daniel's remark, note that $g_n:=f_n+1$ amounts to the matrix transformation

$$
\begin{pmatrix} g_{n+2}\\ g_{n+1}\\1 \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} f_{n+2}\\ f_{n+1} \\ 1\end{pmatrix}.\tag{2}
$$

Then applying eq. $(1)$ to eq. $(2)$ gives
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix} g_{n+2}\\ g_{n+1}\\1 \end{pmatrix}
&=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} f_{n+1}\\ f_{n}\\1 \end{pmatrix}\\
&=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix} g_{n+1}\\ g_{n}\\1 \end{pmatrix}\\
&=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} f_{n+1}\\ f_{n}\\1 \end{pmatrix}\\
&=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} g_{n+1}\\ g_{n}\\1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

So we have $\begin{pmatrix} g_{n+2}\\ g_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} g_{n+1}\\ g_{n}\end{pmatrix}
$
i.e. $\{g_n\}$ is generated by the same matrix multiplication as the usual Fibonacci sequence.